# Simple GPU C++ mining

Tags: gpu-mining, genesis-block, c++

I'm trying to mine a genesis block for an experimental Peercoin clone.

I've already written one using boost threads, and it's been really fun since this is the most processor intensive program I've ever written, but I'm only getting 1M hashes per second, so I'm guessing it's going to take about 72 minutes based assuming initial difficulty 1 and [this equation](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Difficulty#How_soon_might_I_expect_to_generate_a_block.3F) is correct.

Is there a relatively simple way to send the functions to the GPU?

All I'm doing so far is using a "silent" (returns `false` instead of writing the error to `debug.log`) `CheckBlock()` to verify if the nonce is valid or not.

Please show me a simple library that can use the GPU to verify the nonces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This looks like a great lib](https://github.com/kylelutz/compute) that acts as a OpenCL wrapper, at least based upon the short example given on `vector` sorting.

All libraries seem to treat the GPU as if it's some foreign CPU, and while this is no exception, it seems to be the most direct and intuitive.

I haven't been able to test, but if it works as advertised, it looks perfect.

Note: I've tried to sort out CUDA and OpenCL by myself, and I'm just not good enough.  This appeals to my laziness.